# User defined function for extracting gender from string excel data

Tags: python, excel, regex, string, xlwings

I have an excel file with 100,000 rows of patient data including one column that contains patient information in a descriptive text. This text contains gender information as 'male' and 'female'. Some text does not have any gender information. For this I am interested in obtaining an 'na'.

I am trying to use a python user defined function for this data to extract gender by integrating python and excel using xlwings.

I wrote the following function which works within Thonny shell for python.

```
import xlwings as xw
import regex as re

@xw.func
def gender(x):
    if re.search(r'\bfemale\b',x):
        print('female')
    elif re.search(r'\bmale\b',x):
        print('male')
    else:
        print('na')
```

But when I use it in excel, it gives me #NAME? error. I have the excel workbook and python files in the same folder with the same names without any '-' in the names. The import functions work for xlwings and I can run other sample functions. I removed extra spaces from all strings using vba code for replacing vbLf.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Please let me know if you need more information.

Thanks

Comment: are you actually using the 3rd party library `regex`? Could it be that your import should just be `import re` ? (and shouldn't the function actually return something?)

Comment: @ Jon Clements, I used import re instead of import regex as re and they both work in the shell but again not in Excel. I agree with you about returning value in the function but I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Previously, I did have last line of function say "return(gender)" and it worked the same way for me.

Comment: you should not "return gender" since gender is the name of your function, but instead you should replace your print with return

Answer (score 0):

For something as basic as the above, I think you can just do a string contains and not worry about regex:

```
def gender(x):
    return "male" if " male " in x else "female" if " female " in x else "na"

list(map(gender, [
    "brandon is a male patient", 
    "Georgia is a female patient", 
    "Greg is another patient"
]))
# ['male', 'female', 'na']
```

Have said that if you really want to use regex (for example, for learning purposes or what not), you could do something like:

```
m = re.search(r'\b(male|female)\b',"Hello I am a male")
print (m.group(1) if m else 'na')
# 'male'
```